# How to install C# dependencies one time or manually or locally to work offline without internet connection for VS-code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I don't need to download the packages of C# dependencies every time I reopen my project it's consume the time. Also, when you have a slow internet connection like my case will be difficult to going on.

what I get when searching about solution is .vsix solution but it did't help.

```
Installing C# dependencies...
Platform: win32, x86_64

Downloading package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)' (33778 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package 'OmniSharp for Windows (.NET 4.6 / x64)'

Downloading package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)' (47489 KB).................... Done!
Validating download...
Integrity Check succeeded.
Installing package '.NET Core Debugger (Windows / x64)'

Downloading package 'Razor Language Server (Windows / x64)' (59571 KB).................... Done!
Installing package 'Razor Language Server (Windows / x64)'

Finished
```

[Screenshot of downloading package after opening the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohbqx.png)

What I need is to open asp.net core 2.2 projects without re-downloading packages of C# dependencies.

Comment: That extension requires the downloads so as to be working properly. If you do want to avoid it downloading the bits automatically, disable VSCode auto update of the extensions.

Comment: It's not downloading updates, it's downloading dependencies of the project  just Omnisharp, debugger and razor. Also, after downloading if I restart the VScode for any reason it will start downloading again.

Comment: I need the extension to work properly but without downloading the package every time I open my project.

Comment: I said that because I have an extension that does the same (same code from Omnisharp). Ever since VSCode started to auto update extensions, you as an end user might never realize how often an extension has been updated, and each update will trigger a full download of the dependencies (how VSCode works). So your personal feeling/understanding is far from the truth. Like I said, if you disable auto update, then those dependencies will be well cached, and you can update the extension while you have a good connection to download those dependencies again.

Comment: More info can be found in https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-acquire-dependencies-for-visual-studio-code-extensions-9ca828cb168d but probably too much for a VSCode user.

Comment: Thank you for supporting, I'll try it :)

Answer (score 3):

As  [Lex Li mentions in a comment:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58020169/how-to-install-c-sharp-dependencies-one-time-or-manually-or-locally-to-work-offl/58027730#comment102443873_58020169)

> I said that because I have an extension that does the same (same code from Omnisharp). Ever since VSCode started to auto update extensions, you as an end user might never realize how often an extension has been updated, and each update will trigger a full download of the dependencies (how VSCode works). So your personal feeling/understanding is far from the truth. Like I said, if you disable auto update, then those dependencies will be well cached, and you can update the extension while you have a good connection to download those dependencies again.

I have disabled VSCode auto update of the extensions to avoid it downloading the bits automatically and it's working well.

Answer (score 1):

The Omnisharp repository has the document [here](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/wiki/Installing-the-C%23-extension-to-a-computer-without-internet-connectivity). You could pack the platform-specific Omnisharp dependencies to a vsix package, and install it on the target computer offline.

Comment: This document for explaining how can install C# Extension on device hasn't an internet connection. I followed it but not helped.